A rig for a character that has several layers
I have a figure that I modeled that has several layers of clothes and additional elements attached to it (picture attached) and I have no idea how to rig it. I make a rig for one part and another part does not connect. I tried to upload it to Accurig but it turns out that the file is too heavy.
What can be done? Is there a way to rig a character with several layers? I saw that there are more complex characters like knights and the like that they rigged, so I guess my character is also possible, isn't it? In the meantime I was able to make a rig for the character with only the white clothes.

You can probably use the same rig for all the clothes, just parent the clothes to the rig the same way you did with the bare character mesh and then transfer the character's weight maps to the clothes so they move together with the character.
Here is a short video (not mine) that explains the weight map transfer process:   https://youtu.be/yr5KRYz5ybs?si=4bgw_GRV-cZDa-Wh
Disclaimer:   I am not an "expert" or "Blender guru", I just happen to know the answer to this particular question.   Others may have different or better answers.
